# How do i operate on a $2 variable in a javascript string replace function which uses regex object?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

I have to do string replacement in javascript using a regex. But in the second argument of the string replace function, i want to modify the Group variable that got extracted from the regex given in as the first argument. i.e.. i want to pass the group variable $2 to a function and put its return value in place of it. I can also pass this variable i.e.. $2 to an object to get the associated value for it. And this i have to do for all the occurring of that regex pattern in the given string, thats why i am using /gm as regex modifiers.

Here is what i am doing:

```
var regex = /\[?\(.*?\'([^\']+)\'\s*\,\s*\'([^\']+)\'\s*\)[\,\]]\s*/gm;
var ready_data = data.replace(regex, '<abbr pos="'+tagset[$2]+'"> $1 </abbr>')
```

But this is failing, i am getting:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $2 is not defined
```

This is working, if remove the object key value call i.e..

```
var regex = /\[?\(.*?\'([^\']+)\'\s*\,\s*\'([^\']+)\'\s*\)[\,\]]\s*/gm;
var ready_data = data.replace(regex, '<abbr pos="$2"> $1 </abbr>')
```

Is their a way to get this done, either in one line which would be most elegant, OR may be by passing a function which gets called for each regex match according to /gm modifiers.

Comment: I'd pass in a function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `function` as [described by Mozilla (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter):

```
var regex = /\[?\(.*?\'([^\']+)\'\s*\,\s*\'([^\']+)\'\s*\)[\,\]]\s*/gm;
var ready_data = data.replace(regex, function(match, $1, $2) {
  return '<abbr pos="' + tagset[$2] + '"> ' + $1 + ' </abbr>';
});
```